# Keep variable constant

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to try and keep a variable constant. In `class A` After a web service call, I have a variable to hold a value from the `string`which I get from `json_decode`.

Now, `class B` is called after the web service call and I create a new instance of class A. How do I keep the variable constant here? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean here by *constant*?

Comment: That feels a bit abstract, could you paste just that bit of code so we can actually see the order of things happening and which variables get assigned what?

Comment: By constant, I mean the I want the variable to hold the value assigned when I try to access it in a different class after creating its object

Comment: Perhaps do you need a static property? http://globalconstant.scnay.com/2009/12/14/static-variable-inheritance-in-php/

Comment: @sam24 Make the property static. So it's not bound to an instance.

Comment: post your code here and explain with example

Comment: The problem for me was that, I had to change the way the json string was used